# Proving homotopy of 2 paths

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

$A$ and $B$ are $2$ points of affixes $i$ and $1$ respectively, $O$ is the origin.
$γ_1=[AO]∪[OB]$  and  $γ_2=[AB]$ are $2$ paths. 
I know how to prove that $2$ paths are homotopy but in this case I don't how to deal with $γ_1$  because in order to parametrize the $γ_1$ we have to divide it into two segments.
Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have written out a formula for $\gamma_1$ which is subdivided into two pieces:
$$\gamma_1(t) =  \begin{cases}
... &\text{if $0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}$} \\
... &\text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Divide $\gamma_2$ into two segments as well, by subdividing it at its midpoint, obtaining a formula like this (I'll leave it for you to fill in the missing information):
$$\gamma_2(t) = \begin{cases}
... &\text{if $0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}$} \\
... &\text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
And then write the homotopy by subdividing it into two homotopies in the same manner:
$$H(t,u) = \begin{cases}
... &\text{if $0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}$} \\
... &\text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can you write more details? How can we divide it into 2 homotopies

Comment: I added more details.